# pass selectbox option value to php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="eex4.php">
  <label for="text_2">Select the Scheme:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <select name="users" id="users">
    <option value="">Select:</option>
    <option value="1">Sem1</option>
    <option value="2">Sem2</option>
    <option value="3">Sem3</option>
    <option value="4">Sem4</option>
    <option value="5">Sem5</option>
    <option value="6">Sem6</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn" onClick="ResultPage()"/>
</form>
</body>
```

The above code output has selectbox with submit button. when i click the submit button it call the script.

```
<script>
function ResultPage()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 var select = document.getElementById('users');
 var sem = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 var uurl = "eex4.php?q=" + sem;

xmlhttp.open("GET",uurl,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

i need to pass a value of selectbox which option i selected and send to following php file.

**eex4.php**

```
<?php
$schm = $_GET['sem'];
$txt1 = "Semester";
echo $txt1 ." ". $schm;
?>
```

My expected result is:

"Semester[value of option have select]" but it simply displaying "Semester"

can any one find the error..

Comment: If i am understanding you clearly then change this var uurl = "eex4.php?q=" + sem; to var uurl = "eex4.php?sem=" + sem; it will work....

Comment: i checked in javascript using alertbox. it return the correct value, i have doubt in the url passing only.. it is correct?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$schm = $_GET['q'];
```

because you are passing `q` here

```
var uurl = "eex4.php?q=" + sem;
```

The problem is with your form when you click the submit button it posts the data to `eex4.php` and just displays `Semester`.

Change

```
<input type="submit"
```

to

```
<input type="button"
```

So when you click this button the content will load in the page without refreshing the page.

Comment: ya i changed, but the php echo statement does not print the value of select box.. old answer only it return

Comment: @user1709672 what do you mean by "old answer"?

Comment: it just printing value of $txt (i.e) "Semester"

Answer (score 0):

The ajax part has been taken from w3schools. You just have to replace `$schm = $_GET['sem']; to $schm = $_GET['q'];`

Comment: i changed. but the echo statement does not print a o/p like "Semester1"

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var uurl = "eex4.php?q=" + sem;
```

to

```
var uurl = "eex4.php?sem=" + sem;
```

because you are getting 'sem' in eex4.php but passing 'q' to it

Comment: i checked in javascript using alertbox. it return the correct value, i have doubt in the url passing only.. it is correct?

Comment: @user1709672 you are using $_GET['sem'] for getting the value in eeex4.php but you are passing q as parameter to it .. so you have to change it to 'sem'

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$schm = $_GET['sem'];
```

to

```
$schm = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: i changed. but the echo statement does not print a o/p like "Semester1"

Answer (score 0):

You are passing value with through `q`

```
$schm = $_GET['q'];
```

Comment: i changed everything. but the 'q' didn't pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <body>
  <div id="txtHint"></div>
  <form method="post" action="eex4.php">
  <label for="text_2">Select the Scheme:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <select name="users" id="users">
    <option value="">Select:</option>
    <option value="1">Sem1</option>
    <option value="2">Sem2</option>
    <option value="3">Sem3</option>
    <option value="4">Sem4</option>
    <option value="5">Sem5</option>
    <option value="6">Sem6</option>
  </select>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn" onClick="return ResultPage()"/>
</form>
</body>



<script>
function ResultPage()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 var select = document.getElementById('users');
 var sem = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 var uurl = "eex4.php?q=" + sem;

xmlhttp.open("GET",uurl,true);
xmlhttp.send();
return false;
}
</script>
```

**eex4.php**

```
<?php
$schm = $_GET['sem'];
$txt1 = "Semester";
echo $txt1 ." ". $schm;
?>
```